# how to solve error in rxjs/observable in angular4 web api

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Actually, I got this error in my cmd. My nodejs is the latest version. When I clone my angular 4 project to cli I got this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find 
    module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
    src/app/EnquiryDetails/EnquiryDetails.Service.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module 
    '"E:/newfolder/cli/cli/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 
    'Observable'.
    src/app/EnquiryDetails/EnquiryDetails.Service.ts(27,14): error TS2339: 
    Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"private": true, 
"dependencies": { 
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2", 
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2", 
    "core-js": "^2.5.4", 
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0", 
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
```

Comment: Isn't rxjs-compat for angular 6? You might want to try a lower version, maybe rxjs5?

Comment: @rrd i am using angular 4  shall i downgrade the nodejs

Comment: Could you share with us the dependencies in your package.json file?

Comment: It's fully upgraded to ng6.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal then how to slove?

Comment: Either use an old version of `angular-cli`, or fix the errors (`npm i rxjs-compat`, etc.) and enjoy Angular 6.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal how to fix the answer?

Comment: The error says `Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'`, which you can solve by installing the correct package (see answer below)

Comment: Follow the [migration documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) of RxJS 6.

Comment: And [this one](https://update.angular.io/) for Angular itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Angular-cli uses Angular 6 and RxJS6**, so you need to add compatibility with 4/5 through rxjs-compat:

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

---

When upgrading to Angular 6, you can use [the upgrade guide from the Angular team](https://update.angular.io/). I've used it too, and it works very well.

Comment: actually i m using angular 4 is it change to 6?

Comment: Yes, Angular-cli uses Angular 6. Which version of `angular-cli` did you upgrade to?

Comment: i want angular 4 ?

Comment: I upgraded from 4 to 6 about 2 weeks ago, with the release of ng6, and it wasn't very hard. For a medium sized app, it took me just a few hours, and most of the problems came from the new RxJS, which can be solved by the `rxjs-compat`. I really recommend upgrading, but if you really don't want to, you can check for older versions of `angular-cli` I guess.